# Cordova CSP declines local server

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, socket.io, content-security-policy

I have the following cordova content-security-policy in my `index.html`:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https: http: data: blob: 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'">`

My `config.xml` file looks like this:

```
<content src="index.html" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />

<access origin="*" />

<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

I try to connect to a socket io instance, and the connection is successful, but I always get the following error in console:

> Refused to connect to 'ws://192.168.178.52:8091/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=7wM1iepvGxtcJUhcAAAB' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' https: http: data: blob: 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

After that I've tried to add `content-server 192.168.178.52:8091` to the meta tag of my `index` file, without success. I've also tried to add `ws://*/*` and `ws://*` to my `config.xml` (also no success).

**Client**:

```
socketIO.exec = io('http://192.168.178.52:8091');
```

**Server:**:

```
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const server = {};
server.port = 8091;

server.start = function() {
    this.init(port);
    console.log('server running on port:' + this.port);
};

server.init = function() {
    this.io_socket = socketIO(this.port);
    this.io_socket.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log(socket.id); // 7wM1iepvGxtcJUhcAAAB
    });
};
```

All is working as expected expect the error message in the client console. I appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**

If I replace the `'self'` attribute in my meta tag with an `*`, there is no error message at all, so I think the changes are not affecting the whitelist?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the error message with the following line as meta tag in my `index.html`:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src ws://192.168.178.52:8091 'self' https: http: data: blob: 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'">
```